# Run multiple wallets on the same system

Tags: bitcoind

### Setup:

- 10 clients.
- Each client has his own wallet on my secured system.
- An API service manages these wallets.

### Leading Questions:

- Each wallet should run as a separate process of "bitcoind"?
- If so, each "bitcoind" can use the same blockchain files?
- There is a best practice of running multiple wallets on the same system?

Comment: 0.17 (and I think 0.16) has support for multiple wallets in one bitcoind. Even runtime adding/removing/switching wallets. You can manage those using RPC commands. Multiple bitcoind instances can not share the same blockchain files. No experience with this, so can't comment on best practices.

Comment: Thanks @Jannes! Following your answer, I researched a bit and wrote an official answer to that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Using multiple wallets on one "bitcoind" process

#### Follow this steps:

1. Run the bitcoind process.
2. Create a wallet for each of the clients using:

`bitcoin-cli.exe createwallet <client_uniq_id>`

3. When you want to perform any action on any wallet simply use:

`bitcoin-cli.exe -rpcwallet=<client_uniq_id> <your_rpc_method>`

4. Use `""` for `<client_uniq_id>` in order to refer to the default wallet, created by the bitcoind.

Comment: your solution do not specify if running two instances will utilize two copies of the blockchain or use the same ? Also, will this procedure run two wallets simultaneously or only one instance can run at any given moment ? Thanks

Comment: How should I use it with json-rpc? There is no wallet_name parameter in send not list_transactions. So is it possible to run 2 wallets concurrently? So I send coins from one wallet and receive it in another but having just one blockchain and not doing service restart or wallet unload/load between?